# Massless spin 1/2 particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation

Could a massless spin 1/2 particle, or more generally massless half-integer spin particles exist? Does it make sense to say that they could be described for example by the Dirac equation by forgetting the mass term ?

Comment: I believe that the original treatment for neutrinos was like that. Since the mass term couples chirality, a massless fermion would have a neat decomposition as left-handed and right-handed.

Comment: @user23873: yes.  And it's a serious problem for the standard model now--where are the righthanded neutrinos?

Comment: Just to follow up on what @JerrySchirmer said: one possible solution is the suggestion that neutrinos could be Majorana particles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Weyl equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_equation) are a special case of the Dirac equations, and they describe massless spin-1/2 particles.

So far, there are no spin-1/2 particles with zero mass. Neutrinos have masses which are described by the [PMNS matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontecorvo%E2%80%93Maki%E2%80%93Nakagawa%E2%80%93Sakata_matrix), which describes the mixing between different kinds of neutrinos. This kind of treatment explains the discrepancy between the number of neutrinos that come from the sun, and the number measured by solving the Proton-Proton chain problem, and this eventually gives us a lower limit for the masses of different kinds of neutrinos.

So about your question: do they exist? So far, we've found none. But in principle, you could study their dynamics with Weyl equations, and maybe in the future we'll find some.